# How can I check if a Win32 Window pointer is a valid .Net Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

How can I check if a Win32 Window pointer is a valid .Net Control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going to assume that, by "Win32 Window pointer", you mean an hWnd.

You can call Control.FromChildHandle() supplying your hWnd as a parameter. If the hWnd is associated with a .NET Control, then you will receive, as a return value, a reference to the .NET Control representing the control. If the hWnd is not associated with a .NET Control, then you will receive, as a return value, a value of null.

Pseudocode is as follows:

```
Control AssociatedDotNetControl = 
    Control.FromChildHandle(Win32WindowPointerAshWnd);

if(AssociatedDotNetControl != null)
{
    // this is a .NET control
}
else
{
    // this is not a .NET control
}
```

Comment: Matt, I haven't tried that specifically, but I am guessing that it would indeed work.

Comment: It does **not** work if the handle is from a different program. Neither does `Control.FromHandle(`